# Import sonarqube quality profile from xml

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

I am using sonarqube 5.4. How can I import quality profile from .xml for java?

Under sonarqube quality profiles, Creating quality profile from existing file is only available for C# but with a text (Do not use).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to click on the small arrow next to `Create` and choose `Restore Profile` [in the dropdown menu](http://docs.sonarqube.org/download/attachments/6959152/Selection_975.png?version=1&modificationDate=1445015561000&api=v2&effects=drop-shadow), see [documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Profile+Existence+Edits#ProfileExistenceEdits-Backingup/RestoringaProfile). It won't ask you for a language but that's because the language is specified in the XML backup itself.

Comment: Cool. You should [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) this answer if it solved your question.